# Control the setting of $viewValue in a directive's nested ngModel

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a fairly simple UI control that I've modeled as a directive, which is an editor for phone numbers that has two input fields: one for the country code and another for the number.

The directive's usage looks like this:

```
<phone-editor ng-model='phoneNo'></phone-editor>
```

In the directive's declaration, I require ngModel and the template looks like this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="countryCode" />
<input type="text" ng-model="number" />
```

It's clear how to compose and decompose the original model into the two fields.

What I cannot figure out is - how do I use a formatter for the second field such that it displays `(555) 555-5555` instead of the plain number, without defining another directive just to access the ngModel controller of the second input field?

Can I somehow access the child ngModel controller?

Comment: I don't think I'd nest ng-models, rather I would deal with the inputs directly, since I'm already in a directive and that's the place to do DOM manipulation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did a few [searches on the Angular codebase](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3aangular/angular.js/src%20ngModel&type=Code&ref=searchresults) and found something that should work:

```
app.directive('phoneEditor', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    template: '<div>'
      + '<input type="text" ng-model="countryCode">'
      + '<input type="text" ng-model="number">'
      + '</div>',
    link: function(scope, element) {
      scope.number = 555;
      var input1 = element.find('input').eq(0);
      var input2 = element.find('input').eq(1);
      input1Ctrl = input1.controller('ngModel');
      input2Ctrl = input2.controller('ngModel');
      console.log(input1Ctrl, input2Ctrl);
    }
  };
});
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rewh8pk7ZSjicdf0odBD?p=preview).