# AngularJS: Access formController of a form placed inside transcluded directive from parent controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I've created a simple "modal dialog" directive, which uses transclude. I would like to place a form () inside the "modal dialog" directive. I would expect that formController of a form placed inside the directive, is going to be accessible in parent controller's scope, however it isn't. Take a look at the following fiddle, please: http://jsfiddle.net/milmly/f2WMT/1/

Complete code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>AngJS test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/foundation/4.0.9/css/foundation.min.css">
        <style>
            .reveal-modal {
                display: block;
                visibility: visible;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.4/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var app = angular.module('app', []);
            app.controller('appCtrl', function ($scope) {
                $scope.model = {
                    id: 1, name: 'John'
                };
                $scope.modal = {
                    show: false
                };
           });
           app.directive('modal', function () {
               return {
                   scope: {
                       show: '='
                   },
                   transclude: true,
                   replace: true,
                   template: '<div class="reveal-modal small" ng-show="show"><div class="panel" ng-transclude></div></div>'
               }
           });
       </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="app">
        <div ng-controller="appCtrl">
            <div class="panel">
                Id: {{ model.id }}<br>
                Name: {{ model.name }}<br>
                Controller formController: {{ form }}<br>
                Directive formController: {{ myForm }}<br>
            </div>

            <form name="form" class="panel">
                <input type="text" ng-model="model.name">
            </form>

            <a ng-click="modal.show=!modal.show">toggle dialog</a>

            <div modal show="modal.show">
                <form name="myForm">
                    <input type="text" ng-model="model.name">
                </form>
            </div>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

So my question is how to access or is it possible to access directive's formController from parent controller?

Thank you for answers.

-Milan

Comment: Is that the right fiddle? No reference to `$scope.myForm` anywhere.

Comment: There's a {{ myForm }} in HTML, which is same as $scope.myForm, I guess.

Comment: There's also {{ form }}, which references a form inside controller but outside of directive. This one works as expected, but myForm does not get to parent scope - appCtrl's scope :-(

Comment: I really think you linked the wrong fiddle.  There's no `myForm`, there's no `appCtrl`, and there's no `formController` in that fiddle.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I forgot to update fiddle, thank you for notice. I updated the post with complete source as well as correct fiddle link. Thank you again :-)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Because you are using transclude, the directive will create a child transcluded scope.  There is no easy path from the controller scope (003) to the directive's transcluded scope (005):

[image]

(The hard/not recommended path is to go via private property `$$childHead` on the controller scope, find the isolate scope, then use `$$nextSibling` to get to the transcluded scope.)

---

**Update:**
From insights from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15302354/215945), I think we can get the formController inside the directive, then use `=` to get it to the parent.

```
scope: { show: '=', formCtrl: '=' },
...
link: function(scope, element) {
   var input1 = element.find('input').eq(0);
   scope.formCtrl = input1.controller('form');
}
```

HTML:

```
<div modal show="modal.show" form-ctrl="formCtrl">
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/AbmEy/)

[image]

Comment: What generated those beautiful graphics?

Comment: Perfect! :) Thank you Mark. I forked your fiddle to make it more general, so it looks for the form element instead of the first input: http://jsfiddle.net/milmly/utnd6/

Comment: @Langdon, I have a tool that I wrote/am writing. I use GraphViz's dot to generate the pictures.  I have a directive that figures out the scope properties, and some Python code to generate the dot files.

Comment: @MarkRajcok I'd love to see this tool when your finished, or at least a sample `.dot` file where I could copy the styles from! :)

Comment: @apaidnerd, here's a [sample .dot file](https://github.com/mrajcok/angularjs-prototypal-inheritance-diagrams/blob/master/sample_from_new_tool.dot).  If you want to add a label, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/15707752/215945

Comment: @apaidnerd, the tool is finished and on github: [Peri$scope](https://github.com/mrajcok/angularjs-periscope).

Answer (score 10):

Here is my solution:
I create such method in parent controller :

```
$scope.saveForm = function(form) {
  $scope.myForm = form;
};
```

Then I call it in transcluded content:

```
<my-directive>
  <form name="myForm">
     <div ng-init="saveForm(myForm)"></div>
  </form>
</my-directive>
```

After creating directive instance i have form controller instance in parent scope.

Comment: No really actually. Angular supposes controllers to deal with only data model. But anyway it is the best hack i found.

Comment: This method works great when you cannot edit the directive, such as when using Angular UI Bootstrap directives. See my issue here which was resolved with your method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37727443/angular-js-forms-set-pristine