# Expressions not working with directive and $compile

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have angular directive that i use to generate tabs. Based on tabs i need to render my view. Everything works fine , even if i have ng-bind in my view. My issues is with expressions , they not work in view. In directive im using $compile to inject element in scope (controller) and directive receive $scope via   parameter. So in other words if i have this in my view : ng-bind="model.main.details.title" work like a charm, but if use expression like this : {{model.main.details.title}} it doesn`t render the value..

Comment: can u please post the code or make a plunker that shows this problem? It is really hard to find the real problem by just looking at the explanation :-)

Comment: i`ll try , thank you in advance

Comment: I find answer in this topic : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25300163/angularjs-directive-two-way-binding-not-working-with-isolated-scope . My problem was with isolated scope , so i removed scope at all of my directive and access objects from parent directly and this work for me .. I can`t provide example because it`s very complex in my case .. Thank you