# Cannot bind html in AngularJS partial for some unknown reason?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a ng-repeat that uses a partial html file to loop through and display items to a page, for some reason the variables within the partial do not display however the variable {{rule.name}} displays which is outside of the partial displays fine?

rules is an array e.g
rules[0].name = 'My first rule';
rules[0].desc = 'My first desc';
rules[1].name = 'My second rule';
rules[1].desc = 'My second desc';

```
<div ng-controller="RulesController" ng-if="hasManageRules" class="roles canvas-column">
<div ng-repeat="(ruleIndex, rule) in rules">
    {{rule.name}} // this shows the variable fine 
    <div ng-include src="'templates/partial/rule.html'"></div>
</div>
```

// my partial/rule.html file:

```
<div ng-controller="RuleController" class="card-body no-hover form-group" ng-click="unfoldrule(ruleIndex)" ng-class="{'unfolded': rule.unfolded}">
<ng-form name="ruleForm">
    <div class="card-header">
        <div class="card-title" ng-if="!rule.unfolded" ng-bind-html="rule.name"></div>
```

Can anyone suggest why the rule.name variable doesn't display on the ng-bind-html for some reason?

Comment: rules is an array (added an example above)

Comment: Might wanna take a look at the answer I got to a question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35029938/angular-doesnt-set-databinding. I dont know if it helpts though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you dont have to give `ng-controller="RuleController"` inside 
rule.html file.

Comment: cheers Nikhil! will accept shortly.. still getting to grips with Angular :)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the rules variable is not available to the scope of the controller of the template, that's why it's not loading inside the template. If you have a service that sets your rules variable, make sure it's a dependency of your controller definition. Then set $scope.rules = promise/ variable from the service. That should do the trick. Also, as @Nikhil suggested, you don't need to include the controller in the html template, as you stated it once in the main template.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

As you have another "ng-controller="RuleController"" in your included html - you are creating new scope with it's own data.

Try to access data using `ng-model="$parent.rule` instead and do not use `ng-controller` in your child template.