# Variable watch does not fire unless is an array

Tags: angularjs

I have the following markup:

```
<div ng-controller="DataController as vm">
  <div ng-repeat="name in vm.users track by $index">
    {{name}}
  </div>
  <form name="form" validation="vm.errors">
    <input validator ng-model="vm.name" name="vm.name" placeholder="name" type="text" />
    <a href="#" ng-click="vm.add(vm.name)">Add</a>
  </form>
</div>
```

I have the following controller:

```
function DataController($scope) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.name = "Mary";
  vm.users = ["Alice", "Peter"];
  vm.errors = 1;
  vm.add = function(name) {  
    vm.errors++;
    vm.users.push(name);    
  }  
}
```

Every time I add a user I increase the value of errors.

I need to watch this variable inside a directive so I have:

```
app.directive("validation", validation);

function validation() {

  var validation = {
    controller: ["$scope", controller],
    restrict: "A",
    scope: {
     validation: "="
    }
  };

  return validation;

  function controller($scope) {
    this.errors = $scope.validation;
  } 
}  

app.directive("validator", validator);

function validator() {

  var validator = {
    link: link,
    replace: false,
    require: "^validation",
    restrict: "A"
  };

  return validator;

  function link(scope, element, attributes, controller) {
    scope.$watch(function() {
     return controller.errors;
   }, function () {
     console.log(controller.errors);
  });
}
```

The console.log shows the initial value but not new values:
https://jsfiddle.net/qb8o006h/2/

If I change vm.errors to an array, add the values, and watch its length then it works fine:
https://jsfiddle.net/nprx63qa/2/

Why is my first example does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I update your code, you can access to the property scope.vm.errors which is updated, if you debug the code, you will see that the property controller.errors is not updated (after each digest all the watches are called to re-evaluate them). If you access the property errors from the scope you can add the $scope.$watch and make it work. However I would not recommend to have a $scope.$watch inside a directive. But that's up to you :

```
    var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller("DataController", DataController);

function DataController($scope) {

    var vm = this;
  vm.name = "Mary";
  vm.users = ["Alice", "Peter"];
  vm.errors = 1;
  vm.add = function(name) {  
      vm.errors++;
      vm.users.push(name);    
  }

}

app.directive("validation", validation);

function validation() {

  var validation = {
    controller: ["$scope", controller],
    restrict: "A",
    scope: {
      validation: "="
    }
  };

  return validation;

  function controller($scope) {
    this.errors = $scope.validation;
  } 

}  

app.directive("validator", validator);

function validator() {

  var validator = {
    link: link,
    replace: false,
    require: "^validation",
    restrict: "A"
  };

  return validator;

  function link(scope, element, attributes, controller) {
    scope.$watch(function() {
                return scope.vm.errors
    }, function () {
      console.log(scope.vm.errors);
    });
  }

}
```

[https://jsfiddle.net/kcvqn5kL/](http://Link%20to%20the%20code)

Comment: What you would suggest as alternative? Basically,  each validator will be responsible to show a error message. I am using validation directive to define which variable holds the errors without repeating it in all validators since it is always the same ...

Comment: And I am using a  directive as o want to reuse it in my entire aplication.

Comment: In fact that was what i had and worked only with length.

Comment: Let me modify the code and work out something better

Comment: Could you check this code ? http://jsbin.com/jeciraqisi/edit?html,js,output
I was thinking in creating an object in the model called errors, which will have all the errors for each one of your elements. I also added  the attribute element to your directive validator, so you can access to the property error. You can do the validations in your directive or in the controller. I would recommend you to do all the validations of your elements in the $scope.$watch and create a special controller for each one of your directives, but that's up to you

Comment: I like your apuro acho of watching ng model but there is a problem. My validation does not occur on an input value change. This validation occurs after calling an api which responds with the errors which i use to update vm.errors

Comment: Okay, then you can just add a watch to the errors attribute of the element passed by parameter, in this case 'name'. When it changes you just check if you have an error and display it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110085/discussion-between-rodrigo-juarez-and-miguel-moura).

Answer (score 1):

In both of your examples inside `validation` directive `controller` you assign `errors` property a reference to `$scope.validation` value.

In the first example the value is **numeric** and thus **immutable** - `1` - the reference value cannot be modified. The `vm.add` modifies property value of the controller instance. The change is then propagated to `validation` directive `$scope.validation` but **not** to the `validation` directive controller instance `$errors` property.

In the second example the value is an array and thus **mutable** - `[]` - the reference value can be modified. The `vm.add` **does not** modify property value of the controller instance. Thus the `validation` directive controller instance `errors` property value is the very same `Array` instance - hence it's `length` changes.

One way to use a **immutable** value (as in your first example) is to `$watch` a controller function as in [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/fkfg7xwv/):

```
function link(scope, element, attributes, controller) {
  scope.$watch(controller.errors, function (newValue) {
    console.log(newValue);
  });
}
```

Where `controller.errors` is defined as follows:

```
function controller($scope) {
  this.errors = function(){ return $scope.validation; };
}
```

You can find the following answer(s) useful:

- [Why form undefined inside ng-include when checking $pristine or $setDirty()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23686831/why-form-undefined-inside-ng-include-when-checking-pristine-or-setdirty/23687917#23687917)

Comment: Is there any way to solve this? I gave the example with a number but if I use an array which does not change length then it does not work either. And that is what I would like to make it work