# Angular JS access form in scope inside Angular Bootstrap tab

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angularjs-ng-form, angular-ui-bootstrap-tab

I have a form in an Angular JS 1.4.1 prototype.  I have a class on it set when it's dirty.  I am trying to simulate  someone "saving" the form, and therefore it's not dirty, it's "saved" so the changes are still present, but no longer dirty.

Form fragment:

```
<div class="override">
  <tabset>
    <tab heading="My Tab">
      <form name="overridesForm">
        <p><input ng-model="rd.isOverriden" type="checkbox"> Foobar</p>
        <div class="buttons save-cancel">
          <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs" ng-click="overridesForm.reset();overridesForm.$setPristine()">Cancel</button>
          <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" ng-click="overridesForm.$setPristine()">Save with Inline</button>
          <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" ng-click="saveData()">Save with Inline</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </tab>
    <tab heading="Some other Tab">
      blah
    </tab>
  </tabset>
</div>
```

Setting the form to pristine only works for me inline, not in a function in the controller.  So this works:

```
<button ng-click="overridesForm.$setPristine()">Save</button>
```

But not this:

```
<button ng-click="saveData()">Save</button>

//controller:
$scope.saveData = function () {
    $scope.overridesForm.$setPristine();
    toastr.success('Success', 'Data was saved.');
  };
```

I get a runtime error "no object overridesForm defined".

For reasons I have yet to figure out, it works [in this codepen](https://codepen.io/smlombardi/pen/JKGRvG) but not my project.

## UPDATE:

After searching about accessing a form in trancluded content, I hit upon this:

```
 <button ng-click="saveData(overridesForm)">Save with Inline</button>
```

and assign this in controller:

```
  $scope.saveData = function(form) {
    $scope.overridesForm = form;
    $scope.overridesForm.$setPristine();
  };
```

Not sure if this is best practice, but it works. Updated the codepen.

Comment: Do you set the form name to be able to access it in the scope? We need to see more code

Comment: Yes.  Added the form code for clarity.

Comment: A plunkr would be great to be able to test it

Comment: i added a codepen and it works there.  still stuck on why not in my project.

Comment: I should add that this form is inside an Angular UI tab!  I have a feeling that is what my problem is; it is not part of the scope since the angular UI tab transcludes it.

Comment: Try and add the UI tabs to your codepen. You might find the problem yourself while doing it

Comment: I just did that.  Not working.  What I need to figure out is how -- or if -- I can access the form in an ng-transclude.  I see it in my ng-inpector.